# VBA search function with a looping parameter; getting stuck on a single parameter without a modal

Tags: vba, loops, search, find

So I'm working on a loop-based search function that will allow a user to enter multiple search terms and search a Word document for them all at the click of a button (so, if you were to enter 'on' and 'a' and then search this sentence, it will highlight them, one at a time, on the click).  Here is the code:

```
Private Sub cmdfindAll_Click()
Dim w, sentence, temp, finder
Dim i As Integer
Dim response As Integer
For Each sentence In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
    For Each w In sentence.Words
        w = Replace(w, " ", "")
        If w <> lbassocList.List(0) Or w = lbassocList.List(0) Then
        For i = 0 To lbassocList.ListCount - 1
            If InStr(lbassocList.List(i), " ") Then
                temp = Left(lbassocList.List(i), InStr(lbassocList.List(i), " ") - 1)
            Else
                temp = lbassocList.List(i)
            End If
            If temp = w Then
                finder = temp
            Do While temp = w
    selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdNoHighlight

                    With selection.Find
                        .Text = finder
                        .Forward = True
                        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                        .Format = False
                        .MatchCase = False
                        .MatchWholeWord = True
                        .Execute
                    End With
                    selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdBrightGreen
                    finder = ""
                    Exit Sub
            Loop
            End If
            Next i
            End If
Next w
Next
selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdNoHighlight
End Sub
```

Sorry if it looks pretty sloppy...this has undergone numerous quick changes and we're getting frustrated, so we're not too worried about our formatting until we get it working.

Now, the problem we're having is that this will only search and find a single term.  lbassocList is a list of the search terms, and it's increments as intended, but when a word is found we're having trouble breaking out of the with statement and having the code find additional words.

This code actually works as intended when we throw in a message box right after "Do While temp = w"...so we're curious why it's not working now.

Thank you for any help!